# Convergence or divergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}} $: How to argue?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}}
$$
converge or diverge?

My attempt was to write the series as 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{n^{3/2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
$$

The first series can be estimated from below by the harmonic series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{n^{3/2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+2)^{1/2}}{n^{1/2}\cdot n}\geqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty
$$
and hence diverges.

The second series is the harmonic series and hence diverges.

Now, I am not sure what the whole thing does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt is wrong because you can't separate the series into a difference of divergent series. You got an indeterminate form $\infty - \infty$.

You could try to rationalize the numerator:
$$(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n})\frac{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}}$$
Then the series becomes

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n})n^{3/2}}$$

You can use comparison test to conclude.

Comment: I suggest to do not give full  answer suddenly when possible, since it can be not useful for the site nor for the asker who could be interested to solve it by themself. In such latter cases the use of "spoiler" comand can be useful).

Comment: Using "spoiler" command is a good idea

Comment: Yes in this intermediate cases with an asker who have shown his effort and is probably more interested to obtain the result by himself it can be a good choiche. Well done!

Comment: This wasn't and isn't a full answer.  It leaves the determination of convergence/divergence to the asker. It merely suggests rationalizing the numerator, and displays the result upon doing so.  I think it is a fine answer.  Nice work, @LorenzoB.

Comment: With this attempt, the series can be written as $2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ where $a_n:=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n})n^{3/2}}$. Now, by direct comparison test, $\lvert a_n\rvert\leqslant b_n:=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, this means that the series $2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ also converges, even converges absolutely.. - - Am I right?

Comment: @Rhjg, yes you are

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @amWhy, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

We can more effectively use that

$$\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the estimate:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}}<\frac1{n^2} \iff \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n})<1 \iff \\
\sqrt{n(n+2)}<n+1 \iff n^2+2n<n^2+2n+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting :

$2=(n+2) -n=$

$(\sqrt{n+2}-√n)(\sqrt{n+2}+√n) \gt$

$\sqrt{n+2}-√n$, since

$\sqrt{n+2}+√n >1$.

Hence

$\dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}-√n}{n^{3/2}} \lt \dfrac{2}{n^{3/2}}.$

Use comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so $\;\dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}}=o\biggl(\dfrac 1{n^{3/2}}\biggr)$, and the latter series converges.

Comment: That's a nice way but why $\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt n\to 0$?

Comment: That is standard in high school (and your answer shows how it is proved).

Comment: Yes but it seems that the asker ignore that otherwise probably he wouldn't have posted the question. In my opinion at the present state you answer is not complete regarding a crucial point. Moreover once we know it goes to zero we could simply use comparison test. Please consider my observations in a constructive way.

Comment: @gimusi : I think our answers are more or less complementary. They do not aim the same audience, and  I wanted to propose an as concise as possible  answer for those who already have some familiarity with the basics of limits.

Comment: That's ansolutely fine my aim was only to suggest what I thought could make some improvements with that for the asker. But that's of corse all up to you and the answer is fine also in that way. Bye